# Отправка E-mail на Go не работает

Tags: golang, smtp

Программа компилируется, запускается, но ничего не происходит. Исполняемый файл добавил в исключения *firewall'а.* Что я упускаю?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
    // Choose auth method and set it up
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "mailname@mail.com", "password", "smtp.mail.com")

    // Here we do it all: connect to our server, set up a message and send it
    to := []string{"someone@mail.com"}
    msg := []byte("To: someone@mail.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Bla bla bla\r\n" +
        "\r\n")
    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.mail.com:465", auth, "mailname@mail.ru", to, msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не на Яндекс, случаем, отправить пытаетесь? Функция
`smtp.SendMail` почему-то с ним плохо работает.  Возможно,
что-то не так с автоматическим *TLS*. Попробуйте более многословно,
у меня работает:

```golang
var auth = smtp.PlainAuth("", username, password, host)
var conf = &tls.Config{ServerName: host}
var conn, err = tls.Dial("tcp", addr, conf)
// Check err.

var cl, err = smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
// Check err.

err = cl.Auth(auth)
// Check err.

err = cl.Mail(username)
// Check err.

err = cl.Rcpt(username)
// Check err.

var w, err = cl.Data()
// Check err.
_, err = w.Write(msg)
// Check err.
err = w.Close()
// Check err.

err = cl.Quit()
// Check err.
```

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то просто **используйте порт 587** (STARTTLS) **вместо 465** (SMTP over SSL) - smtp.SendMail переключится в режим TLS:

```
to := "to-whom@example.com"
from := "your-user-name@yandex.ru"
mesage := []byte("Test!")

addr := "smtp.yandex.ru:587" // !!!
host := "smtp.yandex.ru"

user := "your-user-name"
password := "your-app-password"
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, password, host)

err := smtp.SendMail(addr, auth, from, []string{to}, mesage)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("Email sent successfully")
```